# Lots of xml files - need search and filter

Tags: c#, .net, xml, search

I have data in xml files (about 5000), need to search and filter this data. It would be wonderful if I can use Fuzzy Search. Suppose need use index? index of the attributes? what should I do use xml database, something like lucene? I prefer .net.

Comment: I edited this to "Lots of xml files" instead of "Lots of xml file." What you had before wasn't really clear either way, but some of us (myself included) were interpreting "lots of xml file" as "an XML file with a lot of data" rather than "many XML files" as you evidently intended. Let me know if I misinterpreted your intent.

Answer (score 1):

For a recordset that small, you may find that [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) meets your needs.

See here for an [XSLT Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/).

Comment: XSLT will at least rationalise the data, but if this is a dynamic search you'll still need xpath or linq-to-xml to get your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)? Sounds like it would be perfect for this situation, allowing you to query the XML with a SQL-like syntax, and the performance shouldn't be too bad over ~5000 records.

Edit: Sorry, I misread the question—it appears you meant 5000 XML files, not 5000 records. Still might be worth a look though.